# Convert Logical output into Matrix form in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have following data in SQL Server Table
Here **ColA** is Row, **ColB** is Column and **ColC** is *(Row, Column)* Value as we have in matrix

```
ColA | ColB | ColC
1    | 1    | 1
1    | 2    | 2
2    | 1    | 3
2    | 2    | 4
```

and I want output as a matrix form

```
ROWCOUNT  | ResB | ResC 
1         | 1    | 2    
2         | 3    | 4
```

Comment: If this is meant to be a *general* transformation, probably better to do it in a spreadsheet. Despite some superficial resemblances, tables/result sets in SQL are very different to spreadsheets. Notably, *rows* and *columns* are very different beasts in SQL.

Comment: What does `ResB` and `ResC` represent? Neither are in your initial data. What have you tried so far? You say "matrix", are you implying you're using a matrix in SSRS? SQL Server doesn't return a matrix, it returns a dataset/resultset.

Comment: `ResB`, `ResC` are just output column name, I want to write a query which can give me said output from given input table.

Comment: Can you at least describe your transformation then please? It isn't inherently obvious; and any answer that does give the right result set would be guesswork and may be incorrect for your non-sample data.

Comment: Data is like row, column and value for (row, column) having a separate row for each entry. I want to convert it into a matrix as provided in output.

Comment: I would suggest using loops and fill a temp table

Comment: Please provide all the data and update your question.

Comment: Your output doesn't make sense to me. The output column names are completely different that those of the table and the values are just nonsensical. I will be happy to show a dynamic way to do this if you can update your post with some details that are consistent.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is what you want to do

```
select
    ColA, max(case when ColB = 1 then ColC end), max(case when ColB = 2 then ColC end)
from
    myTable
group by ColA
```

Comment: It works for above sample data.
But above is sample data of a 2x2 matrix, there can be data for 3x3,4x2,5x3...
How can I improve this SQL in such use cases?

Comment: @ParthPatel then please provide **representative** sample data. This is why I asked for details of your transformation. If you don't provide data with is representative of your actual data, we can't give you a solution that works for it; only the sample data. Give several examples, not a single overly simplified one.

Comment: @ParthPatel, use dynamic SQL

Comment: In the table, it can have three columns: Row, Column, Value
Data will be provided as described above, currently, I have provided data for 2 row and 2 columns. It can have data for X no of Columns and Y no of Columns and I want the output in such a way it looks like the matrix where at (1,1) it holds value for (Row, Column) defined in a table.

Comment: @ParthPatel, I meant dynamic pivot